# Binding script triggers to tabs in Filemaker (pro 12)

Tags: scripting, triggers, tabs, filemaker

I've got this weird problem with FileMaker Pro 12. I am using it for the first time, so I am pretty sure I'm doing something wrong, but I can't figure out what.

I have created a layout with three tabs, and I am trying to load a different layout when I click on a tab. Google's vox populi says the right way of doing this is to set a script trigger to each of the tabs, whereby the script would 'goto' my desired layout. Easy.

The problem starts here: when I set a script trigger to one of the tabs, for some reason this is set to all tabs. If I change one, it changes all.

The weird thing is that when I created the tabs initially I was able to set a different trigger for each tab, but all of a sudden this was no longer possible.

Would appreciate some help on this, I am sure I did something to trigger this behaviour but can't find on Google exactly what.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a single script trigger for all tabs, and when that script fires, check the currently selected tab and perform the appropriate action/subscript.

Comment: I had thought something like this, but I got stuck in how to check the selected tab?

Comment: GetLayoutObjectAttribute("MyFirstTab", "isFrontTabPanel"), e.g.